# Formula for Variance in statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

So I've been watching this lecture on LinkedIn Learning, on statistics. On the subject of standard deviation for a discrete probability distribution table.

Please see below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlUbU.jpg

To get the variance, the lecturer subtracts "the square of the mean" from the "WEIGHT TOTAL" (which is the sum of "# of Drinks, Squared" times the normalised weight or relative frequency).

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how this works and how it yields the same result as the standard variance formula (sum of all data points' distance from the mean divided by "N-1").

Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: The variance of a real random variable $X$ is defined as $$\mathsf E((X-\mathsf E(X))^2)=\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2,$$ and the lecturer used the right-hand side

Comment: By the way, there is some need for caution: The variance of a *discrete* random variable is $\frac1{\color{blue }{n}}$ and so on, you don‘t use $n-1$ in the denominator. The $n-1$ is only used if you are calculating a sample variance: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation

Answer (score 1):

$$\sigma^2 \equiv \cfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2}{n}$$

$$\sigma^2 = \cfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i^2-2\mu x_i+\mu^2)}{n}$$

$$\sigma^2 = \cfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}{n} - \cfrac{2\mu\sum_{i=1}^n  x_i}{n}+\cfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n \mu^2}{n}$$

$$\sigma^2 = \cfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}{n} - 2\mu^2 + \mu^2 = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 - \mu^2 \\\square$$

If you are familiar with Expectation, this is equivalent to

$$Var(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2$$

For more details on the proof above, [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/summarizing-quantitative-data/variance-standard-deviation-population/v/statistics-alternate-variance-formulas) is a Khan Academy video on the topic.